Unable to deploy spring boot 3.x to weblogic 14.1.1
I'm trying to deploy Spring Boot 3.x on WebLogic 14.1.1 then it's throwing an error as shown in the screenshot below. But when I downgraded Spring version to 2.x, the deployment works as expected. Could you please help me to solve this issue?
enter image description here

Do not post images. Edit your question to add a complete stack trace and log messages generated during your application deployment.
You can take the tour and read How to Ask for more guidance on how to write a good question.
tour : https://stackoverflow.com/tour
how to ask : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

(1) Oracle WebLogic Server 14.1.1 is Java EE 8 and Jakarta EE 8 (https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/weblogicserver-datasheet-1411.pdf) (2) Spring Boot 3.x use Jakarta EE  9/10. import package is jakarta.xxx. (3) Spring Boot 2.x use Jakarta EE 8, import package is javax.xxx (4) Conclusion: Since you are using weblogic 14.1.1, you can only use Java EE 8 / Jakarta EE 8, so you can only use Spring Boot 2.x.
